# How does the War Caster feat interact with opportunity attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, opportunity-attack

When an enemy disengages one of your allies in combat, does this provoke an opportunity attack for all PCs that can see the enemy and respond (i.e. weapon ready) including with long-range attacks like from a range with a readied bow, or is it that only the PC that the enemy was in melee with at the time of disengaging gets an opportunity attack?

For example: Say there is a monk in melee combat with the enemy, a ranger about 50 feet away with a readied longbow, and a sorcerer about 45 feet away with the War Caster feat and an attack spell with a range of 60 feet. Would the sorcerer be able to cast a long-range reaction attack spell and would the ranger get an attack of opportunity in response if the enemy disengages the monk?

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn how things work around here. There are several incorrect assumptions in your question, there also seems to be more than one question. Are you asking about long-range attacks of opportunity or the war caster feat? Thanks for participating and happy gaming.

Comment: If you are asking about when you can make opportunity attacks in general this is a duplicate of [When can I make opportunity attacks?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/44402/48759) If you are asking a different question please [edit] to make it clearer.

Comment: Note that "Disengage" is an enumerated action in 5e, but it's not clear to me from the question that you're talking about that action. I think the question would be clearer if you specified if when you say "disengage" you mean "take the Disengage action" versus, say, "move out of the monk's reach."

Answer (score 6):

From the [Basic Rules](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/basicrules), p. 74:

> **You** can make an opportunity attack when a hostile
>   creature that you can see moves out of **your** reach.

The monk can make an opportunity attack, the ranger and sorcerer cannot.

If the trigger for the ranger's [Readied](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Ready) longbow was "When the creature leaves the monk's reach" or "When the creature moves" then they can choose to fire the longbow.

[War Caster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/war-caster) (PHB, p. 170) still requires that you be the one who can make the opportunity attack:

> When a hostile creature's movement **provokes an opportunity attack from you**, you can use your reaction to cast a spell at the creature, rather than making an opportunity attack. The spell must have a casting time of 1 action and must target only that creature.